# choices value of select in an inline form in admin django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

please I want to select the list of cycles by Program_de_bourse, know that in my actual form I can select all the cycles , but I just want to select the cycles linked to Program_de_bourse my foreign key Program_de_bourse = id of Program_de_bourse
the model.py

```
 class Cycle(models.Model):
   Programme_de_bourse = models.ForeignKey(Programme_de_bourse, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   Objet_programme = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=objet_CHOICES, verbose_name='Cycle'
    )
   def __str__(self):
     return self.Objet_programme
```

..

```
class Discipline(models.Model):
  Discipline = models.ForeignKey(Disc, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Discipline_cycle')
  Cycle = models.ForeignKey(Cycle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  Programme_de_bourse = models.ForeignKey(Programme_de_bourse, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
  related_name='Programme_de_bourse_id')


  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.Discipline)
```

my admin.py

```
 class Programme_de_bourseAdmin(ExportActionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets =  [
    ('Programme',               {'fields': ['Programme']}),
    #'classes': ['collapse']
       #
   ]

   list_display = ["Programme",]

   inlines = [CycleInline, DisciplineInline, ConditionInline, EtablissementInline, DocumentInline]


 class DisciplineInline(ExportActionMixin, admin.TabularInline):
 )
    model = Discipline
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK8hN.png)

Comment: you can create a form for class **DisciplineInline** and add a filter over there

Answer (score 0):

try this

you can create a form for class DisciplineInline and add a filter over there

this might work with some changes

```
class DisciplineForm(forms.ModelForm):
     Programme_de_bourse = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset='....') # your filter 
     class Meta:
        model = Discipline
       fields = ('....')

class DisciplineInline(ExportActionMixin, admin.TabularInline):
 
    model = Discipline
    form = DisciplineForm
```

Comment: I'm new in Django, I tested your solution and it doesn't work for me , this is my code                                                   
' cycle = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cycle.objects.filter(Programme_de_bourse = 7) )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Discipline
        fields = ('cycle','Discipline') '

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me to get cycle by Program_de_bourse_id = 7, now i want replace 7 with real id of Program_de_bourse, so how a can get the id of Program_de_bourse from my function Program_de_bourseAdminrer

```
class DisciplineForm(forms.ModelForm):
cycle = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Cycle.objects.filter(Programme_de_bourse=7)) 
class Meta:
    model = Discipline
    fields = ('cycle','Discipline')
```